# How to break a loop using a function

Tags: python, python-2.7

How do I break a loop that outside the function by using the functions to do so?
Here is my code:

```
for x in range(5):
def display_grid():
    if px == 1:
        print
        print "Invalid input, please Use the format \'x,y\'"
        print
        return
    elif nx == 1:
        return
    print '\n' *30
    print p1 + p2 + p3 + p4 + p5 + p6 + p7 + p8 + p9 + p10 + p11 + p12 + p13 + p14
    return
while i > 0:
    display_grid()
    break
```

The return only breaks the function and the loop being a conditional it will keep printing the statements above only 5 times , I want it so that it will keep printing it until the conditions are not met. Thank you!

Comment: You need to `return` some value from function (`my_value = display_grid()`), and depend on that value (e.g. if value was `True` or `False` either `break` from loop or stay in it.

Comment: Indeed. Allowing a function to implicitly break out of a loop could be very confusing. For example, what would happen if the function is called outside a loop?

Comment: Actually, there are serious indentation problems with your code. What does the forx∈ran≥(5)forx∈ran≥(5)for x in range(5) loop contain? Is the function definition meant to be inside it? How about the whi≤whi≤while loop? What are `px` and `nx`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoiding the obvious problems in the initial code (it may well have been edited by the time you read this), the usual approach to this type of problem is to have the function return a value which is used to condition the outer loop, thus:

```
def foo():
  ...
  return need_to_be_called_again()

while foo():
    ... # Do something
```

Here `need_to_be_called_again()` is simply pseudocode for determining whether or not foo() needs to be called again. Alternatively, you could actually make `foo()` a generator

```
def foo():
    while need_to_be_called_again():
        ...
        yield True

for _ in foo():
    ... # Do something
```